# Minor web-forms designer thingy

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

As a high-school student [that pretty much has C# knowledge of a first degree] - I got an assignment for the Israelish 'Bagrut' exams [which are the final, most important exams in high-school] - before we actually went through the materiel in-class [about 3 years earlier.]

It was to make a simple dynamic website, maybe a basic social website or an online-store, with importance of server-side ASP.NET.

My teacher gave me a book from 2006 called 'ASP.NET & XML Web Services' - and I've started learning.
The problem is, I have `VS2010 Ultimate` with .NET FW 4 installed, and apparently, is majorly different from the `C# Express` that the book author has.

On my VS, the `Design Editor` of the HTML is not allowing me to have the `WinForms` level of freedom, but makes me write the CSS myself, not show me the common XY based designer, but something like a blog WYSIWYG - without the freedom of moving stuff around.

As I do not want to work too hard converting the book instructions to my VS, I would like to know if its possible to get the [probably obsolete] `WinForms` - `WebForms` designer - and not by downloading a very old version of VS.

I've tried playing around a bit with VS, and found out that the book used `System.Web.UI.Page`, while my VS uses `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm` - even manually changing to `UI.Page` did nothing to the designer.

Is it possible to 'go back' to the `WinForm` type of designer? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use your teacher book? There are a lot of nice modern resources on line. Also you can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) Visual Web Developer for free and use it to develop.

Comment: It's really a point of whether the minister of education accepts my work or not.  I don't want to be too pesky about it, more then I am about the point that they do not allow using the `break` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do what you want. You are referring to the ugly, terrible, thing-that-should-have-never-been-created-in-the-first-place grid layout thing that Visual Studio 2003 used to have. Learn a bit of HTML. Tables are easy enough to learn and lay out things properly on your markup.

Comment: Oh please, no tables for the layout, there too many web sites out there already using them

Comment: @AndreiDrynov I understand, but the OP is looking for something fast and easy to learn without having to go into much detail about CSS. I think learning to use `tables` is a very good start for him.

Comment: It's for a SCHOOL job - I prefer MVC[3]. The thing is that this is something that my primitive school requires.

Comment: @Icarus - I have to disagree.  Just because learning something the wrong way is a quick and easy way to do it doesn't mean it's a good way to do it.  Learn it properly the first time so you're not having to unlearn it and re-learn the right way later.

Comment: Starter Kit or templates could be useful too. You can use Visual Studio Extension Manager to get them.

Comment: 'Primitive school', asking for projects like that. I feel old already )))

Comment: @Zannjaminderson since when learning to use `table` is wrong or not useful? Why would he have to `unlearn them`? I don't really think is a big deal to do this for the kind of project the OP is facing.

Comment: @Icarus - "Learning to use `<table>`" is not the problem.  Learning to use `<table>` *for layout* is the problem.  Maybe it's not a big deal for a small project, but why not just learn how to do layout right to begin with?

Comment: You probably have not seen page layouts with 7 (!) tables nested in each other just to position elements. Throw in 1MB of JavaScript in each plus AJAX and you will understand what we meant. Tables are for tabular output like sales list

Comment: @Zannjaminderson Again, I agree with your statement, but doing the layout with divs and CSS rules has a steeper learning curve; it's not something that one can pick up easily in 20 minutes; tables are. You said it better: `Maybe it's not a big deal for a small project`. And I agree with you again on this.

Answer (score 2):

Designing webforms is much different than designing winforms, as the designer uses HTML for the markup. There's really no way to change that, but there should be a design view that allows you to drag and drop, and move things around similarly to how you would a windows form.

As for the design aspect of your site, there is probably no way to escape CSS. The design view should help you with the layout, but most of the styling and aesthetics will have to do be done in CSS.

[image]

1. Page shown in design view
2. Toolbox
3. View (Design/Split/Source)
4. Solution Explorer
5. Properties Window
6. Run (F5)

Comment: James, do you actually use it? It does not show styles and layout accurately and breaks my nice code on the page

Comment: Personally, I *never* use design view. I don't like the HTML it outputs, and I find the source view easier to use on-the-whole.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between Content (where you can move your 'stuff') and Code in the HTML Designer, but the point is that VS2010 (be it Express or Ultimate) is for professional development and if you are unwilling to get to know HTML and CSS, there is not point in using it.

You'd be better using other tools like Adobe Dreamweaver or free tools like Amaya

Update: Try WebMatrix

Comment: It's for a SCHOOL job - I prefer MVC[3] [with HTML & CSS etc]. The thing is that this is something that my primitive school requires.

Comment: Just remembered about WebMatrix. http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/. It is probably what will help you build a web site fast and learn good things at the same time (Razor syntax is here to stay)

Answer (score 1):

Umm, I'm no web developer and I have no real opinion about whether WebForms is really as evil as Icarus says, but I'm going to have to just throw out there as an alternate answer to his - don't learn to lay out your HTML using tables - HTML tables are for tabular data.  Learn to layout your HTML using `<span>` and `<div>`, because that is the correct and standards-compliant way to do it.  Also because every time you use tables for layout, a skinny-jeans-and-thick-rimmed-glasses wearing hipster dies somewhere, and we need them and their creativity.

Comment: I didn't say WebForms are evil. What I said was that Visual Studio 2003 used to have a Grid Layout designer, where you could just drop your HTML elements anywhere you wanted using X,Y coordinates. This, of course, made the pages render properly ONLY on IE. Microsoft removed it on the next version of VS (fortunately).